# stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft - prompt=select_account

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, thephpleague

I have already implemented oAuth authentication with Microsoft and Google, but with Microsoft I run into the problem that the user cannot select his account and only the account currently selected in the background is submitted. However, this account is not necessarily authorized.

How can I add the option parameters like "prompt=select_account" to the "stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft" package?

Ressources
https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Thanks for your help

I have already tried the following, but without success.

```
        $provider = new Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft([
                // Required
                'clientId'                  => $row['clientId'],
                'clientSecret'              => $row['clientSecret'],
                'redirectUri'               => $row['redirectUri'],
                'prompt'            => 'select_account'
        ]);
```